# how to replace plain url with hyperlinks in html doc

Tags: java, html, regex, hyperlink, regex-negation

I am trying to replace plain link to hyperlink in an html document.
and my logic is

```
private static final Pattern WEB_URL_PROTOCOL = Pattern.compile("(?i)http|https://");

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if (text != null) {
            // Escape any inadvertent HTML in the text message
            text = EmailHtmlUtil.escapeCharacterToDisplay(text);
            // Find any embedded URL's and linkify
              Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(text);


            while (m.find()) {
                int start = m.start();

                if (start == 0 || text.charAt(start - 1) != '@') {
                    String url = m.group();
                    Matcher proto = WEB_URL_PROTOCOL.matcher(url);
                    String link;
                    if (proto.find()) {
                        lower case protocol link.
                        link = proto.group().toLowerCase() + url.substring(proto.end());
                    } else {

                        link = "http://" + url;
                    }
                    String href = String.format("<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>", link, url);
                    m.appendReplacement(sb, href);
                }
                else {
                    m.appendReplacement(sb, "$0");
                }
            }
            m.appendTail(sb);
        }
```

This code is successfully find out all links in a html doc .but problem is it also find the hyperlink.So i want to exclude the hyperlinks and want to find only plain links 
for example it should exclude

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><a href="awbs://www.google.com" target="_BLANK">https://www.google.com</a> normal address https</p>
```

but plain link `https://www.google.com`  should be replaced by a hyperlink

Edit
if doc contain text like this - 
1. https://www.yahoo.com

2. https://www.google.com normal address https

so here i want to replace  `https://www.yahoo.com` with

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><a href = "https://www.yahoo.com>https://www.yahoo.com</a></p>
```

and it should not effect 2 at all .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand you to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) here.

#### Sample code

```java
String text = "<html><head></head><body><a href='http://google.com'>Don't change this link</a> Change this: http://yahoo.com foo.com</body></html>";
Document d = Jsoup.parse(text);
String newHtmlCode = "";
String oldHtmlCode = d.outerHtml();
List<TextNode> textNodes = d.body().textNodes();

Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher("");
for (TextNode textNode : textNodes) {
    m.reset(textNode.text());

    String fragment = "";
    while (m.find()) {
        fragment = m.replaceAll("<a href=\"\\*\\*\\*$1\">$1</a>");
        textNode.replaceWith(new Element(Tag.valueOf("span"),"").html(fragment));
    }

    newHtmlCode = d.outerHtml().replaceAll("\"\\Q***\\E(?!https?://)", "\"http://").replaceAll("\"\\Q***\\E(https?://)", "\"$1");
}

System.out.println("BEFORE:\n\n" + oldHtmlCode);
System.out.println("----------------------------");
System.out.println("AFTER:\n\n" + newHtmlCode);
```

#### Output

```
BEFORE:

<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a href="http://google.com">Don't change this link</a> Change this: http://yahoo.com foo.com
 </body>
</html>
----------------------------
AFTER:

<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a href="http://google.com">Don't change this link</a>
  <span> Change this: <a href="http://yahoo.com">http://yahoo.com</a> <a href="http://foo.com">foo.com</a></span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it possible do without using parsers. i am looking for regex.

Comment: @Subham Check my answer I use a regex for finding the plain links. Jsoup is pretty fast.

Comment: @Subham Check my new answer.