# How to convert text within a textarea into a URL like Facebook does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am providing users with a textarea into which to input descriptions of their products. I am also allowing people to comment on the products like on Facebook.

Sometimes these posts include a URL to further information and I would like to be able to detect that part of the text as a URL and wrap it in an anchor `<a>` element once it is published to the page.

The text is being submitted by a form and goes to the server as plain text. I use a `REReplace()` regex replace function on the server-side to convert carriage returns into `<br>` tags so that it looks correct on the page.

However I don't know how to parse out the URL parts and wrap them in an anchor tag. Should it be done on the server-side or should I use jQuery on the client-side to wrap URLs on the fly? If I do it on the fly and there's hundreds of comments on the page with URLs - wouldn't this affect the page's performance?

If its on the server-side whats the best way to do it? I have jSoup on the server but couldn't work this one out because no HTML gets submitted from the textarea - only plain text e.g.

> This new TV features 4K HDR technology. Read more at http://www.google.com

**UPDATE:**
This is not a duplicate question of others. I am not asking how to convert plain links on a webpage into working ones (I can use linkify for that).

I am asking how to linkify on the server-side using jSoup or something similar. The textarea does not pass any HTML code to the server and neither can I wrap the text in anchor element because its a textarea and the inserted text doesn't appear in the DOM from what I can tell using Firebug.

Comment: Please check following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links

Comment: I found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431113/how-to-replace-plain-url-with-hyperlinks-in-html-doc